# Может ли союз "или" соответствовать по значению союзам "и", "а также"?

Tags: союзы

Может ли союз "или", когда употребляется в предложении при присоединении последнего члена перечисления, соответствовать по значению союзам: "и", "а также"?

Comment: @Алексей Владимирович 777, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> Может ли союз "или", когда
> употребляется в предложении при
> присоединении последнего члена
> перечисления, соответствовать по
> значению союзам: "и", "а также"?

**Может.** Из "Объяснительного словаря русского языка" под. ред. В.В. Морковкина:

> ...Употр. для присоединения к ряду
> слов, обозначающих однородные в
> определённом отношении предметы,
> действия, события и т.п., ещё одного
> аналогичного по значению слова, к-рое,
> завершая перечисление, имеет характер
> некоторого добавления к уже
> перечисленному.
>
> *Люди сидели на стульях, в креслах или просто на полу.*

Answer (score 2):

Может - в случаях с отрицанием перечисляемого.

Запрещается входить в кинотеатр на коньках, курить в кинозале и (или, а также) пользоваться радиотелефонами во время сеанса.